# Convert the regular expression to a NFA

Tags: computability, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I have to convert the following regular expressions to a NFA:

1. $$(0 \cup 1)^{\star} 000 (0 \cup 1)^{\star}$$
2. $$(((00)^{\star} (11)) \cup 01)^{\star}$$
3. $$\emptyset^{\star}$$
4. $$a(abb)^{\star} \cup b$$
5. $$a^+ \cup (ab)^{\star}$$
6. $$(a \cup b^+)a^+b^+$$

For the regular expressions $1-3$, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, and for the expressions $4-6$, $\Sigma=\{a, b\}$.

I have done the following:

[image]

Is this correct??

How is the NFA for the regular expression $3.$ ??

**EDIT1:**

[image]

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: Since $\emptyset^* = \{\varepsilon\}$, the NFA for expression 3 is just one state which is both start and accept state with no outgoing transitions.

Comment: I see... Are the other NFA's correct?? @mrp

Comment: $(O \cup 1)^*$ is accepted by the one state automaton $\leftrightarrow 1 \xrightarrow{0,1} 1$. Therefore you can simplify a lot your solution for (1).

Comment: I have added a new automaton for $(1)$. Could you take a look and tell me if this automaton is better?? @J.-E.Pin

Comment: @MaryStar Much better, but you could still merge the first two states and the last two ones.

Comment: I edited my initial post again and added a new automaton. Is this correct?? What about the other NFA's?? @J.-E.Pin

Answer (score 1):

Your automata 1 is correct,

However the other are not:

2) You should be able to read several 00 before reading the 11 in the upper part since the regular expression is $(00)^*11$

4) a should be accepted by your automaton. You have to move the upper accepting state from the end of the sequence $abb$ to it's beginning (it's an $(abb)^*$ not $(abb)^+$

5) Again it's $(ab)^*$ hence the lower accepting state should be at the beginning of the sequence ab, and you should add a $\epsilon$ that allow to restart this sequence.

6) It's a $b^+$ you should be able to read several $b$'s hence add a loop reading $b$s on the lower state (between b and a).